# Property not found on object of … error debugging properties on NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, core-data

I created  a new project with objective-c using coredata as so many times before, but I noticed the newer Xcode is not allowing me to debug the properties on my `NSManagedObject` which refer to another different `NSManagedObject`.

Let me explain with an example. MLP stands for MyLittleProject

I have the following objects:

```
MLPPerson+CoreDataProperties.h

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) MLPCard *card;

MLPCard+CoreDataProperties.h

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *cardID;
```

when I am in the code and try:

`NSLog(@“%@“, myPerson.card.cardID);`

it works great, however when I try to print in the debug console:

`po myPerson.card.cardID`

I get an error:

> error: property ‘card' not found on object of type ‘MLPPerson *'

I am quite confused as this used to work great in older projects I worked on.

Answer (score 15):

I found the answer: the reason why this worked before is because the properties were in a class and now they are in a category.

i.e. the content of MLPPerson+CoreDataProperties.h in other projects was part of MLPPerson.h.

Now, to make the debug console print these, you need use

`po [myPerson card] cardID]`